# How to Handle Daemons in C Linux

Tags: c, linux, handler, daemon

I did some research on how I could manipulate daemons using the C language on Linux.

But, I found nothing.

Does anyone know a way or some library that I could do this manipulation daemons?

Like a stop or start an daemon, or reload config of daemon, but without use `system()` or `popen()`.

Someone know how can i try to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you don't.. you just `kill` to send appropriate signals to the daemon process, e.g. SIGHUP for reload, SIGTERM for shutdown, etc...

Comment: One convention is to use kill to send signals to a daemon, read up on kill(2,3) and signal(7).  Many daemons will save their process id in a pid file, which can be read to open/send them a signal.  For example SIGHUP to reload config, SIGTERM to terminate, SIGSTOP and SIGCONT for pause/restart.

Comment: Notice that daemons are actually somehow distribution specific. There are probably not exactly the same on Debian than on Fedora. The kernel probably don't know about daemons, it only manage processes.... Some of which are conventionally daemons.